# List All Highcharts on Page in Svelte

Tags: highcharts, svelte

We are investigating multiple new web development stacks in an effort to get away from VB.NET. I have created a page using Svelte 3 architecture to replicate what we have on one existing .NET-based page. We use Highcharts for our charting library. I am able to get the charts to show up. However, other logic we use to get list of all charts on the page always returns an empty array:

```
export const DestroyChartReferenceByClassName = (className) => {
    var cssClassName = className;
    jquery(Highcharts.charts).each(function (i, chart) {
        if (typeof chart !== 'undefined') {
            if (chart.container.classList.contains(cssClassName)) {
                chart.destroy();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

When I call this method it runs without errors. However, `Highcharts.charts` is an empty array. What is the preferred method to iterate over the Highchart charts on a Svelte page?

Comment: Hi @wergeld, Using `Highcharts.charts` is a good idea, but maybe you are using two or more Highcharts instances in your project? Alternatively, you can store every created chart in some custom global variable.

Comment: @ppotaczek There is only one installed highcharts (from my package.json). I can create my own custom variable to store charts. My concern is if a basic command like `Highcharts.charts` does not work, what else is non-functional?

Comment: So maybe there is something wrong with Highcharts imports and more than one instance is created? However, empty `Highcharts.charts` array should not cause any problems in basic usage.

Comment: @ppotaczek it does cause issues as I have multiple charts per page and the `Highcharts.charts` array is still empty. I need to be able to know how many I have rendered for other functionality in the code. I did nothing outside of adding to my packag.json and install the highcharts npm package.

Comment: Then you can use a custom variable to store charts. However, could try to reproduce the problem in some online code editor? Here is a jsfiddle with svelte: https://jsfiddle.net/dapo/skvucdhj/23/